# Qt - QMAKE_LFLAGS throws "Command not found" when using -L

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, linker, qt-creator

I am trying to compile a qt widgets project under Ubuntu 14.04

My .pro file has a line that looks like this:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib
```

I could hardly find any documentation on the `-L` flag but judging by other projects on the internet, the syntax looks fine. However, both Qt Creator 3.5.1 and NetBeans 8.1 fail to compile (or should I say link) the project with the same error:

```
L/usr/local/lib: Command not found
```

Notice that the hyphen before the `L` is now gone.
However, I managed to build the project using the terminal with the following set of commands:

```
make clean
~/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake 
make
```

With `clean` being vital as terminal displays the same error without it.
Then I made sure my `make` is located at `/usr/bin/make` and I tried to modify my build steps in Qt Creator to look like this (project build directory is filled with black):
[image: My toolchain in Qt Creator looks like this]

This gave me no results either, it still fails to compile on any build/rebuild within IDE with the very same error. Similar errors appear with literally any other flags I try to put there (for instance, `-pthread` gives me `pthread: Command not found`).

I have spent hours trying to solve the problem. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after spending a few more time I noticed that the head of my .pro file looks like this:

```
QMAKE_CXX = "g++-4.9"
QMAKE_CC = "g++-4.9"
QMAKE_LINK = $$(CXX)
```

with `CXX` being an environment variable that *was supposed to be* equal to `g++-4.9`. Turns out it wasn't. After making it look like:

```
QMAKE_CXX = "g++-4.9"
QMAKE_CC = "g++-4.9"
QMAKE_LINK = "g++-4.9"
```

the problem got fixed and it compiled successfully. Yaay!

Comment: Usually you should not overwrite `QMAKE_CXX`, `QMAKE_CC` or `QMAKE_LINK` by hand, but configure your kits appropriately. To link stuff to your library prefer to add to the qmake variable `LIBS` instead of `QMAKE_LINK`. That is the intended and more portable way of using qmake.